# Async await - nested then depending on result of previous await

Tags: javascript, typescript, async-await, promise

Consider the following non-negotiables:

There are 3 async functions that I have to work with and they're below, I cannot change these.

```
    async asyncCall1({ caseId }: { caseId: string }) {
        const response = await this.apolloClient.query({...})
        return {
          ...response,
          data: caseResponse,
        }; 
    }


    async asyncCall2({ caseIdFromCall1 }: { caseIdFromCall1: string }) {
        const response = await this.apolloClient.query({...})
        return {
          ...response,
          data: caseResponse,
        }; 
    }

    async asyncCall3({ caseIdFromCall3 }: { caseIdFromCall3: string }) {
        const response = await this.apolloClient.query({...})
        return {
          ...response,
          data: caseResponse,
        }; 
    }
```

What I need happen is:

1. Need one field from response of asyncCall1 to feed into asyncCall2, I then need one field from asyncCall2 to feed as input to asyncCall 3. Essentially the calls have to happen sequentially.
2. I need to do add to a list from asyncCall1 and asyncCall2 and asyncCall3 and return a boolean based on a condition while processing asyncCall3.
3. A way to handle exceptions in each? - Perhaps return a certain boolean value in each case we run into an error in any of the calls.
4. I'm happy if a solution gives me a way to move away from **nested hell**

Here is my try

```
    const checkAuthorization = (input: string) => {

        let coalate = []

        dependency1.asyncCall1({ caseId: input })
            .then((call1RawResult) => {
              console.log("Inside caseResult: ", call1Result);
              return { data: call1Result.data.caseProperties.caseId1 }; //This is the response from call 1 that I want to pass to call 2
            })
            .then((call1SpecificField) => dependency2.asyncCall2({caseId: call1SpecificField.data})) //This is where I attempt to use value from asyncCall1
            .then((call2RawResult) => {
              const caseId2 = call2RawResult.data.caseProperties.caseId2; 
              coalate.push(caseId2); //Also push to list
              return { data: caseId2 } //Do some operation and pass this on for use in the next call
            })
            .then((call2SpecificField) => dependency3.asyncCall3({caseId: call2SpecificField.data}))
            .then((call3RawResult) => {
              const caseId3 = call3RawResult.data.caseProperties.caseId2; 
              coalate.push(caseId3); //Also push to list
              
              //Finally return true or false if input is found in consolidated coalate list
              return coalate.includes(input);
            }).catch((error) => { //If any issue in any of the above dependency calls - return false.
              console.log(error)
              return false;
            })

     }
```

1. My issue is that I seem to be hitting the line `Inside caseResult:`, but never beyond that.
2. When calling `checkAuthorization()`, I need the computed boolean value from inside the catch block atleast, but it just comes out as undefined.

Comment: Consider dependency1 to be a dependency containing `asyncCall1` method

Comment: This sort of thing is much easier if you actually use async and await for it instead of nesting and chaining piles of then callbacks.

Comment: Let me check that out, I just didn't quite understand how to use result of 1st async await in the second call. I figured using thens was the only way

Comment: `coalate` should be a `Set<string>` - not an `Array<string>` - that way the `.contains` check will be `O(1)` instead of `O(n)`.

Comment: `const caseId3 = call3RawResult.data.caseProperties.caseId2; ` <-- Shouldn't this be using `caseProperties.caseId3`?

Comment: answer to `2.` you don't return anything from `checkAuthorization`

Comment: @Jaromanda X: When trying to provide a reproducible example, I missed it

Comment: But, that would explain the issue, so ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- It's 2023 - using `await` instead of `.then()` [callback-hell](http://callbackhell.com/) results in code that's much easier to read, write, and understand, in my opinion.

  - BTW, using `await` does not mean you *have to* `await` each `Promise` when they enter the scope: it's perfectly valid to store a returned/received `Promise` in a local and then `await` that local later-on - this is how you can implement certain kinds of nontrivial Promise logic.

---

I'll tackle each of your goals individually and incrementally:

> - Need one field from response of `asyncCall1` to feed into `asyncCall2`.
> - I then need one field from `asyncCall2` to feed as input to `asyncCall3`.
> - Essentially the calls have to happen sequentially.

That's straightforward:

(btw, `svc: MyService` is the `object` with those `asyncCallN` methods).

```
async function run( svc: MyService, input: string ) {

    const result1 = await svc.asyncCall1( { caseId: input } );
    console.log( "result1: %o", result1 );
    const caseId1 = result1.data.caseProperties.caseId1;

    const result2 = await svc.asyncCall2( { caseId: caseId1 } );
    console.log( "result2: %o", result2 );
    const caseId2 = result2.data.caseProperties.caseId2;

    const result3 = await svc.asyncCall3( { caseId: caseId2 } );
    console.log( "result3: %o", result3 );
    const caseId3 = result3.data.caseProperties.caseId2; // <-- Not `caseId3` ?
}
```

---

> I need to do add to a list from `asyncCall1` and `asyncCall2` and `asyncCall3` and return a `boolean` based on a condition while processing `asyncCall3`.

Again, straightforward:

(though [I feel a `Set<string>` should be used](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) instead of an `Array<string>` / `String[]` because your code will be performing set-membership checks, which are `O(1)` (good) for `Set<T>` but `O(n)` (bad) for `Array<T>`).

```
async function run( svc: MyService, input: string ): Promise<boolean> {
    const caseIdsSet = new Set<string>();

    const result1 = await svc.asyncCall1( { caseId: input } );
    console.log( "result1: %o", result1 );
    const caseId1 = result1.data.caseProperties.caseId1;
    caseIdsSet.add( caseId1 );

    const result2 = await svc.asyncCall2( { caseId: caseId1 } );
    console.log( "result2: %o", result2 );
    const caseId2 = result2.data.caseProperties.caseId2;
    caseIdsSet.add( caseId2 );

    const result3 = await svc.asyncCall3( { caseId: caseId2 } );
    console.log( "result3: %o", result3 );
    const caseId3 = result3.data.caseProperties.caseId2; // <-- Not `caseId3` ?
    caseIdsSet.add( caseId3 );

    return caseIdsSet.has( input );
}
```

---

> A way to handle exceptions in each? - Perhaps return a certain boolean value in each case we run into an error in any of the calls.

Only catch exceptions if you actually need to: **Unless** you *expect* any of those `asyncCallN` calls to fail during normal program operation **and** your program needs to *do something* during an error condition (such as rolling-back any persisted changes so-far) then you *don't* need to litter your program code with low-value `catch` statements.

Even if you want to just want to log any errors (e.g. `catch( err ) { console.error(err); }`) you still shouldn't normally need any `catch` blocks: most JS environments will/can still log exceptions at the point at which they are thrown by a `throw` statement. If this is a JS that runs in a web-browser then you should *also* be listening to `window`'s `'error'` event for unhandled JS exceptions.

---

Your `asyncCallN` functions seem to be using Apollo - if so, then you should (largely) ignore the vague, general advice that I wrote above and [instead follow Apollo's guide to error-handling](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/error-handling) with their library.

---

> I'm happy if a solution gives me a way to move away from nested hell

This answer.

Comment: Will accept once I test this out. Thanks a ton. I have two questions:

1. If I am to return a boolean from this - think of this while async run method as an authorization check, if I simply `authcheck = run(input)..`, is it possible for me to get undefined in authcheck? Because I didn't do `authcheck = await run(input)`?, since without having an await - I've read it continues execution in a non blocking manner.


2. How do I thank you better than an Accept Answer?

Comment: @ababuji 1. Do `const isAuthorized = await run( /*args*/ );`. You will _need_ the `await` operator  to get the `bool` value. You will **never** get an `undefined` result from the expression `( await run( /*args*/ ) )` with my approach.

Comment: _"since without having an `await` - I've read it continues execution in a non blocking manner"_ - yes, but the only reason for _not_ immediately `await`-ing the `run` function's returned `Promise` is if you want your program to do _something else_ while/until the `run` function asynchronously completes. Do you actually have any logic you want to run in-between `const authPromise = run( /*args*/ );` and `const isAuthorized = await authPromise;` ? ...if not, then just do `const isAuthorized = await await run(...)`.

Comment: @ababuji _"How do I thank you better than an Accept Answer?"_ - I see you're at Amazon - a lifetime of infinite credits for AWS would be nice  - or maybe fix Alexa's voice-recognition: when I ask my Echo to play "The Answer by Unkle" it _always_ thinks I'm asking for songs by Beyoncé...

Comment: A lifetime of infinite credits? Even in house AWS teams don't get to use unlimited AWS to build their backend. Thanks a lot for your help. I hate this frontend work. You can tell I struggle.

Comment: @ababuji Yeah but your stock vesting schedule tho - you'll get to retire as an Amazon stock millionnaire within a decade and _abandon computers entirely_ while I'll still be making low-effort posts here on SO while waiting for my code to compile - sounds like you made the better deal with the devil than me ;)